How to fetch record based on common value
This is my table
CREATE TABLE students 
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    Name  TEXT NOT NULL,
    Version Text,
    Topic TEXT NOT NULL,
    Department TEXT NOT NULL
);

-- insert some values
INSERT INTO students VALUES (1, 'Asset A','1' ,'Song','Song');
INSERT INTO students VALUES (2, 'Asset B','1','IndustryX', 'IndustryX');
INSERT INTO students VALUES (3, 'Asset C','1','Strategy', 'IndustryX');
INSERT INTO students VALUES (4, 'Asset D','1','Strategy', 'IndustryX');
INSERT INTO students VALUES (5, 'Asset D','1','Cross Function', 'IndustryX');
INSERT INTO students VALUES (6, 'Asset E','1','Cross Function', 'IndustryX');
INSERT INTO students VALUES (7, 'Asset F','1','Cross Function', 'Song');
INSERT INTO students VALUES (8, 'Asset G','1','Cross Function', 'Song');
INSERT INTO students VALUES (9, 'Asset G','1','Strategy', 'Song');
INSERT INTO students VALUES (10, 'Asset H','1','Strategy', 'Song');
INSERT INTO students VALUES (11, 'Asset A','2' ,'Strategy','Song');
INSERT INTO students VALUES (12, 'Asset A','1' ,'Cross Function','Song');
select * from students

Fetch some values - this is my output:



id
Name
Version
Topic
Department




1
Asset A
1
Song
Song


2
Asset B
1
IndustryX
IndustryX


3
Asset C
1
Strategy
IndustryX


4
Asset D
1
Strategy
IndustryX


5
Asset D
1
Cross Function
IndustryX


6
Asset E
1
Cross Function
IndustryX


7
Asset F
1
Cross Function
Song


8
Asset G
1
Cross Function
Song


9
Asset G
1
Strategy
Song


10
Asset H
1
Strategy
Song


11
Asset A
2
Strategy
Song


12
Asset A
1
Cross Function
Song



Expected output: only rows with Id 3, 10 and 11 should be returned.
When Department is Song and either is either song or cross function for that version, that row should not appear.
When Department is IndustryX and either is either Industryx or cross function for that version, that row should not appear.

The question is unclear, at least to me. Can you share the output you're trying to get?

Why would the rows with id 4 and id 9 need to be filtered out? They are identical to id 3 and id 10, which you indicated you do want.

ID 4 and 9 have Cross Function in their name+version group so they are excluded

I think the question needs to be more explicit about  the role that Topic plays.

I found 1 way to do it. I think i can remove the left joins and use Exists in the WHERE clause.
WITH NameVersionsWithSong as
(  
SELECT ID,CAST(Name as VARCHAR(512)) as vcName ,CAST(Version as VARCHAR(512)) as vcVersion
FROM students
WHERE cast(Department as VARCHAR(512)) = 'Song'
),
 NameVersionsWithIndustryX as
(  
SELECT ID,CAST(Name as VARCHAR(512)) as vcName, CAST(Version as VARCHAR(512)) as vcVersion
FROM students
WHERE cast(Department as VARCHAR(512)) = 'IndustryX'
),
 NameVersionsWithCrossFunction as
(  
SELECT ID,CAST(Name as VARCHAR(512)) as vcName, CAST(Version as VARCHAR(512)) as vcVersion
FROM students
WHERE cast(Department as VARCHAR(512)) = 'Cross Function'
)    
  
SELECT s.id, s.Name, s.Version, s.Topic, s.Department
FROM students s
LEFT JOIN NameVersionsWithSong nvs ON s.ID<>nvs.ID AND CAST(s.Name as VARCHAR(512))=nvs.vcName AND  CAST(s.Version as VARCHAR(512)) = nvs.vcVersion
LEFT JOIN NameVersionsWithIndustryX nvx ON s.ID<>nvx.ID AND CAST(s.Name as VARCHAR(512))=nvx.vcName AND CAST(s.Version as VARCHAR(512)) = nvx.vcVersion
LEFT JOIN NameVersionsWithCrossFunction nvc ON s.ID<>nvc.ID AND CAST(s.Name as VARCHAR(512))=nvc.vcName AND CAST(s.Version as VARCHAR(512)) = nvc.vcVersion
WHERE (cast(Department as VARCHAR(512)) = 'Song' AND nvs.ID IS NULL AND nvc.ID IS NULL AND cast(s.Topic as VARCHAR(512))  not in ('Song','Cross Function')  )
      OR 
      (cast(Department as VARCHAR(512)) = 'IndustryX' AND nvx.ID IS NULL AND nvc.ID IS NULL AND cast(s.Topic as VARCHAR(512))  not in ('IndustryX','Cross Function'))
        

fiddle



id
Name
Version
Topic
Department




3
Asset C
1
Strategy
IndustryX


10
Asset H
1
Strategy
Song


11
Asset A
2
Strategy
Song




Among rows with the same name and version, disqualify if any of them have particular combinations of topic and department:
with dataX as (
    select *,
        count(case when Department in ('Song', 'IndustryX') and Topic in (Department, 'Cross Function') then 1 end)
            over (partition by Name, Version) as disqualifiers
    from students
)
select * from dataX where disqualifiers = 0;

You shouldn't be using text. These columns contain simple varchar data. Use varchar(max) if you truly do need long types but that is highly unlikely based on the sample.

I think your solution is concise. I think it can work if just do all of the casting first. https://dbfiddle.uk/kI6iQ9in

@BartMcEndree Yeah, I did notice your casting. I didn't care to deal with that and I haven't had to worry about all that in a very long time!
